# Java - bijective mapping between local vars in source code vs byte code

Tags: java, bytecode, local-variables

Is there a bijective mapping between the local variables in the source code of a Java method and the byte code?

E.g.

source code:

```
int x = ...
A a = ....
if (...) {
    B b = ....
}
```

I can assume in the byte code there will be space for 3 local vars, where the first relates to x, the second to a and the third to b?

Will the ordering of the local vars in the bytecode relate to the ordering they are first used in the Java source?

EDIT: I'm aware that for longs and doubles Java uses two local variables and that there are local variables reserved for method params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a bijective mapping between the local variables in the source code of a Java method and the byte code?

There isn't in general because addresses used by variables out of scope are reused for other in-scope variables. For example:

```
for (int j = 0;;) {}
int k  = 0;
```

`k` can reuse the same location as `j`.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the compiler can optimize your code and therefore variables could be eliminated. Simply think of a piece of code like this:

```
int a = 1; // only used to initialize b
int b = a;
```

Then it would be unnecessary to keep space for `a`. Or, for your example

```
int x = 42; // only used to initialize a
A a = new A(x);
```

Comment: -1 This is incorrect. Javac does not do optimizations like this for good reason - you want the local variables to appear when debugging (it also simplifies compilation). Remember, this isn't C! The JVM optimizes the bytecode at runtime, so there's no need to do compile time optimization anyway.